# Python if condition not working as anticipated

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
word = ""
if (letter=="a" for letter in word):
    print("a found!")
```

which prints `a found!` even though word variable is empty. Why is this happening? And what is the right way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition you used in `if` returns a generator expression `<generator object <genexpr> at 0xefd89660>` which is always **`True`**. 
To verify what your condition returns,

```
print(letter=="a" for letter in word)
# <generator object <genexpr> at 0xefd89660>
```

Hence you get what you got.

**Right way**:

```
word = ""
for x in word:
    if x == 'a':
        print('a found!')
```

Iterate through `word`, compare if it equals `'a'` and do whatever if condition is satisfied.

Or even better:

```
if 'a' in word:
    print('a found!')
```

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because the statement `(letter=="a" for letter in word)` is a *generator*. Your if statement checks if that generator is a "truthy" object (lots of things in python evaluate to true for convenience -- nonempty lists, nonempty strings, etc...) and then prints `"a found!"` since the generator evaluates to `True`.

Instead, you probably want something like the following.

```
word = ""
letter = "a"
if letter in word:
    print(f"{letter} found!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`(letter=="a" for letter in word)` returns a generator. Since generators don't seem to have have a `__len__` nor a `__bool__` it always evaluates as true.

The code you want is this one:

```
word = ""
if ("a" in word):
  print("a found!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use

```
for a in word:....
```

but if you persis your manner, you should write as follows:

```
import numpy as np
word = "abc"
if np.any(list(letter=="a" for letter in word)):
    print("a found!")
```

pull elements out of the generator, and use np.any() to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers explain the why it is not working, here is just a way to use list comprehension to solve your problem:

```
word = "StackOverflow"
[print(letter + " found in:", word) for letter in word if letter == "a"]
```

Which returns:

```
a found in: StackOverflow
```